# How to implement horizontal gallery in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gallery, uislider

HI guys,

I am trying to implement a horizontal gallery like option in my iPad app. I'v heard that there is an option called "gallery" in Android to do this kind of implementation. But, is there any way in which we can implement this feature in iPad..I am attaching a screen shot to make the question more clear.... (**gallery can be seen in the bottom of the screen shot**)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate a scrollView and call your datas inside it. Hope the below snippet will help you. The snippet will create a horizontal scroll view.

```
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height-35)];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
 self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
 [self.scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault];
 scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
 scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
 [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake("GIVE YOUR WIDTH",0)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 1):

That can help you: https://github.com/Kastet/APCarouselView

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [UIPagecontroll](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

You might also take a look at the PageControl sample code in Xcode.

Comment: page control is different with respect to my requirement shown in the above figure. I need to display more images on the screen at a time and the images in the queue should sync with the slider event...

Comment: Then you should use a UIScrollView and add a slider to it. Use the UIScrollviewDelegate to response to scrolling and update your UISlider accordingly. Create actions when the user uses your slider and update the UIScrollview.